# Display Result in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am a newbie in android development, so plz try to explain complex steps.

I want to know what codes to write for the following process:-

**Activity1** takes number input via **EditText** then perform some actions on it, lets say it multiply it with 2, then send *this new number* to another activity **Activity2** where it is displayed.

Mainly i want to know how to display the new number in an activity.

Thnx in Advance.

Comment: Go through Intents in Android. You really had to google or search this question on SO before posting here.

Comment: Try to search in `Google` or `Stackoverflow` first. After ask as question while you didn't get any solution.

Comment: See this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069609/pass-data-from-one-activity-to-another-but-go-to-the-other-activity-later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the data from one activity to another activity..

**Main.java**

```
Intent it=new Intent(Main.this,Expense.class);
it.putExtra("a", food);
startActivity(it);
```

**Second.java**

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
{
    String fud=b.getString("a");
}
textview.setText(fud);
```

Comment: thnx! thats exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in the following question shows how data can be passed between activities.Before that read about intents carefully.

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: Liking of another person's question/answer is not a way of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this example

add this in activity 1

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
myIntent.putExtra("UserId",UserId);
myIntent.putExtra("UserName",UserName);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

add this in activity 2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
UserId=intent.getStringExtra("UserId");
UserName=intent.getStringExtra("UserName");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Intents in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) is what you are looking for